# make rebuild target depending on zip file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Why `make` rebuilds the target (I suppose) if the dependency is a binary file?

To reproduce:

1. create (and enter it) a new empty directory
2. download the [GameLift SDK](https://gamelift-release.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/GameLift_12_22_2020.zip) (it is just an example: the `Makefile` content on this question is an example with this file)
3. create a simple `Makefile` with the content below
4. issue more times the `make` command

```
all: GameLift_12_22_2020/GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2/GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.1/CMakeLists.txt

GameLift_12_22_2020/GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2/GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.1/CMakeLists.txt: GameLift_12_22_2020.zip
    unzip -oq GameLift_12_22_2020.zip
```

I would have expected to see the `unzip` command to be executed only first time I issue the `make` command, but it continue to be executed in next `make` runs... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities, we cannot know which is the case with the information you've provided.

The first is that the file `GameLift_12_22_2020/GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2/GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.1/CMakeLists.txt` is not present in the zip file, so the second time make runs it looks to see if that file exists and it doesn't, so it re-runs the rule.  If, in the same directory you run `make`, you use `ls GameLift_12_22_2020/GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2/GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.1/CMakeLists.txt` (after the unzip runs) and you get "file not found" or similar, this is your problem.

If that's not it, then the problem is that the timestamp of the file in the zip file is older than the zip file itself, and when unzip unpacks the file it sets the timestamp to this older time.

So when make goes to build it finds the `CMakeLists.txt` file but the modification time is older than the zip file, so make unpacks the zip file again to try to update it.

You can use `ls -l` to see the modification time on that file.  If this is the case you should touch the file when you unpack it, so it's newer:

```
GameLift_12_22_2020/GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2/GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.1/CMakeLists.txt: GameLift_12_22_2020.zip
        unzip -oq GameLift_12_22_2020.zip
        touch $@
```

Comment: The file is in the zip file (I'm not so noob :D ), the key was the timestamp of the extracted file! Conclusions: I'm noob, but not so much :)